# How to apply TAM (technology acceptance model) to UX design and testing?

Tags: user-behavior, surveys, measuring

The [Technology Acceptance Model](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Technology_acceptance_model) (TAM) combines a number of a number of factors to create a model that predicts user decisions influence their decision about how and when they will use the technology.

I could not find any information on how to calculate and interpret the results. Appreciate if anyone can share your knowledge. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, there is a substantial body of research on how the TAM works and its application to measure factors that are very closely aligned with what we would generally classify as elements of user experience:

> TAM is one of the most influential extensions of Ajzen and Fishbein's
>   theory of reasoned action (TRA) in the literature. Davis's technology
>   acceptance model (Davis, 1989; Davis, Bagozzi, & Warshaw, 1989) is the
>   most widely applied model of users' acceptance and usage of technology
>   (Venkatesh, 2000). It was developed by Fred Davis and Richard Bagozzi
>   (Davis 1989, Bagozzi, Davis & Warshaw 1992[1]). TAM replaces many of
>   TRA's attitude measures with the two technology acceptance
>   measures—ease of use, and usefulness.

**Long answer:**

The terms modern UX design uses to describe the different elements are encapsulated by usability (equivalent to ease of use in TAM), utility (equivalent to usefulness in TAM) and engagement (which is a result of factors in TAM such as external variables, attitudes and behavioural intention).

The difficulty with testing and measuring any of these factors is that often you have to derive or decompose the metrics to its individual component. For example, a conversion rate might capture both the usability (it might be hard to find the call-to-action on the page because it is poorly designed) and utility (if the content has no value to the user they won't consider the call-to-action). User engagement is often a combined measure of different metrics collected on user behaviour such as those reflected in click maps and eye tracking studies, but these results can also be influenced by usability (spending time looking for how to do something instead of processing the content) and utility (different people place value on page content different).

So basically TAM is trying to match what would probably be large volumes of quantitative data related to usage (e.g. page visits, time spent on page, etc.) to the qualitative factors that impact on these types of measures. This allows you to monitor the overall user experience of the system while you alter the factors to try and improve it. Just as a side note, it is important to also determine the external variables as they may influence the actual system use in ways that can't be explained by (or exerts more influence over) usability and utility alone.

**Short answer:**

The TAM model is simply a theory or concept that tries to explain how different factors affect the actual or resulting usage of a system. It is about comparing quantitative usage data collected when different factors that influence usage changes. So the first step is to find usability and utility tests that are suitable for the type of system you are designing and benchmark it against analytics related to usage information.

As you add more forms of user testing and work out the characteristics of your system design that affects usability and utility, you can gain more confidence that the improvements in usage results from delivering a better user experience rather than external factors.

**Conclusion:**

You won't necessarily find a template to apply TAM to your system because it depends on what type of system you are designing, but there are plenty of tests and tools you can use to create something that will help you implement TAM.